# Experimental design for complex temporal pair interaction data

Tags: anova, modeling, interaction

**Context:** I am faced with what I believe is a non-trivial modelling problem that I have been assigned as part of my post-doc. My expertise is in the area of graph / network theory so I have found myself struggling with all the available modelling options and language.

**The problem is as follows**: In an observational dataset we have a continuous response which is the outcome of two individuals interacting. The individuals belong to a time-invariant factor with 6 levels so there are 36 possible types of interacting pairs. Furthermore the data are aggregated monthly and there are $t=\{1,..,T\}$ months. We want to understand the dependence of the outcomes on the factors with a model of this form:

$$Y_{i,j,t} = G_i + G_j + G_i*G_j,$$

where $i,j$ are individuals and $G_i,G_j$ their factors.

With regards to time we are only interested in whether the points fall either side of a significant event but do not want to differentiate between months belonging to the same side of the event. So essentially data can be further aggregate on two disjoint time spans on either side of the event with repeated observations.

So considering the two time period dataset our issues are the following:

1. *The dataset is highly unbalanced:* The membership of these groups is highly heterogeneous, there can be for example differences of up to 1 or 2 orders of magnitude  between the occupancy levels of the factor, leading to a highly unbalanced design. Furthermore there are correlations in the interaction rates of factor levels which complicates things even more.
2. *There are repeated observations due to the time aggregation.*

My question is: **What is a good experimental design to understand the main and interaction effects of the factor?** For example, one solution could be to sample each side of the event to deal with the balance but in that case the repeated observations problem remains.

Comment: I am confused what you are asking. As stated, your question is about "a good experimental design." But this doesn't seem right because you aren't in a position to design an experiment; the data is already collected and you are simply analyzing it. So then perhaps your question is about what is a good statistical model for handling these data. But then this is also confusing because you already wrote a model in your post which you say is the model you desire. So then it's not clear what you need from us. Could you give some hints about what a satisfactory answer to your question might look like

Comment: Just a preference, but perhaps you could describe what the study involves with a few more concrete details. I.e., what does Y represent, what is the context of measurement?